# If I embed a tweet the rendered tweet already comes with hard-coded inline styles which messes the original margin

Tags: css, twitter, embed

I want my embedded tweet to has margin of 0 for example, but the twitter library will hard code the margin inline. So there is no way to update to my style without js.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `!important` to boost the precedence of your own style rules e.g.

```
div.tweet {
 margin:0px !important;
}
```

See http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/ for more details and explanations.

Comment: You are right, I've tried with !important at first but somehow it didn't worked.. Thanks